# Error al hacer la distribución de Poisson (Probabilidad) en Java

Tags: java, matemáticas, bucles

Me encuentro intentando hacer una calculadora que saque la probabilidad de un evento utilizando la **[distribución de Poisson]**[1](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuci%C3%B3n_de_Poisson), el hecho es que logro que me de los dos primeros casos correctamente pero luego cambian los resultados probabilisticos.

Utilizo un **ciclo `for`** para realizar la misma operacion 5 veces, aplico la formula y espero los resultados.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                double probabilidad = Math.pow(promedio, i)*Math.pow(Math.E, -promedio)/i;

                System.out.println(probabilidad);    
            }
```

El problema es que recibo los dos primeros resultados pero el resto son incorrectos, me doy cuenta de esto al compararlos con una calculadora online.

Resultado que devuelve el programa utilizando promedio 1.625:

[image]

Resultado que devuelve una calculadora online utilizando únicamente 3 ocurrencias(desde donde empieza a decolver resultados distintos) y un promedio de 1.625:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si coloco 2 ocurrencias coincide...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Gracias de antemano!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que la división no es por i sino por el factorial de i.
Por lo tanto podrías declarar la siguiente función:

```
public int factorial(int n)
{
    if(n == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }               
    return n * factorial(n-1);
}
```

Por lo tanto tu for quedaría así:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        double probabilidad = Math.pow(promedio, i)*Math.pow(Math.E, -promedio)/factorial(i);
        System.out.println(probabilidad);
}
```

Espero que te ayude a solucionar el problema. Con 2 y 1 te funcionaba pues el factorial de 1 es 1 y el de 2 es 2.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono! Toca aprender un poco mas de matemática jaja! Saludos!